# Autowiring collection of beans in annotation driven context

Tags: java, spring

Usercase:

We got a bunch of autowired beans, each of it annotated by @Service, say B1, B2 and B3, with the same interface BInterface.

In the method of class A I need to engage one of them via the interface depending on key string, say "b1", "b2" and "b3".

I could use hashmap Key -> BInterface for that but I am interested is it any Spring elegant (idiom) way to inject the bean that I need dynamically. Also I know that getBean is considered as an anti-pattern.

I don't know is it important, but context defined as annotation-driven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring way to do this is to have your three beans implementing three different interfaces (or subinterfaces) and then reference the three interfaces with the `@Autowired` annotation. After all, if the three beans have different functionality, it makes sense to do it this way.

You could also have a bean containing the three and have that be `@Autowired` so you don't need the three references everywhere.

I'm not even sure how the `@Service` would get properly wired if there are more instances of the same interfaces. It would work for concrete classes but I don't think it would work for many implementation of an interface.

Here's an example of what I suggest:

```
interface BInterface{ /*...*/ }

@Service
class B1 extends BInterface{/*...*/}

@Service
class B2 extends BInterface{/*...*/}

@Service
class B3 extends BInterface{/*...*/}

@Service
class BProvider {
  @Autowired
  private B1 b1;
  @Autowired
  private B2 b2;
  @Autowired
  private B2 b2;
  public BInterface get(String k) {
    switch(k){
      case "b1": return b1;
      case "b2": return b2;
      case "b3": return b3;
      default: return b1;
    }
  }
}

BClient {
  @Autowired
  private BProvider provider;
  public void doSomething(){
    BInterface b = provider.get(/* one of the three */);
    // use b ...
  }
}
```

As an alternative, you could make `BProvider` configurable and configure it with a `Map<String,BInterface>` using XML configuration.

So it would be:

```
@Service
class BProvider {
  @Autowired
  private Map<String,BInterface> bs;

  public BInterface get(String k) {
    return bs.get(k);
  }
}
```

And you have to define your map in the configuration file. To do so, you can manually create your beans in the XML file or I believe you can use a `BeanPostProcessor` to add them to the collection.

Comment: the beans has same functionality described by interface, but they are intstances of different classes. it is working now but code is ugly, I want to refactor it. actually i don't understand why I can't autowire beans with the same interface, using qualifiers at least

Comment: Thanks, that is certainly how it written right now. But fact is that i need to write all this cases hardcoded, I thought I could do something more elegant using collections.

Comment: Yeah but you have to do it only once. The other option is a combination of `BeanPostProcessor`s and an autowired map as above, but that can get messy. I recommend using the `BProvider`, it's the cleanest way.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta - why not just call applicationContext.getBeansOfType(BInterface.class) in @Configuration? That way you avoid 1) unnecessary hard-coding of bean names to beans, Spring already registers bean of class B2 as "b2" and 2) avoid additional factory (BProvider is NOT a @Service) to duplicate what Spring already does.

Comment: That's absolutely an option. However, depending on how spread out this particular service is, it might lead to code bloat, i.e., the "anti-pattern" mentioned in the SO, where the application context (or bean factory) is unnecessarily exposed to many classes. It's an anti-pattern because it couples too many parts of the application with the IoC framework. Moreover, using a `BProvider` allows to better encapsulate the business rationale behind having many services implementing the same interfaces, making this fact explicit which is always a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have xml config or not. But you can autowire by name. Define 3 beans b1, b2, b3 in spring config and have setter method for those bean name in the class

```
<beans>
...
    <bean name="b1" class="some.package.B1" />
    <bean name="b2" class="some.package.B2" />
    <bean name="b3" class="some.package.B3" />
...
</beans>


Class UserOfBInterface{
BInterface b1;
BInterface b2;
BInterface b3;

public void setB1(BInterface b1){
this.b1 = b1;
}

public void setB2(BInterface b2){
this.b2 = b2;
}

public void setB3(BInterface b3){
this.b3 = b3;
}
}
```

Another way is using @Qualifier annotation rather than using setter injection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Amit. Unfortunately I am not allowed to use different methods for engaging those B's beans. The interface of A is predefined something as public void useBean(String name);

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the @Resource annotation to pick-up a resource by name:

```
@Resource(name = "b1")
BInterface b1

@Resource(name = "b2")
BInterface b2

@Resource(name = "b3")
BInterface b3
```

Comment: I can do that. Thanks, I will actually try. But it does not solve the problem of engaging dynamic way.

Comment: Ah.  In that case, I'd probably create a BFactory that has a method that takes your string and spits back the appropriate BInterface.

Answer (score 1):

This is the cleanest way I can think of, it does rely on getBeansOfType(), but only once in @Configuration, NOT at runtime where "dependers" resolve their own dependencies.

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class DefaultDatabaseConfiguration {

    @Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, MyService> services() {
        return applicationContext.getBeansOfType(MyService.class);
    }
}
```